# jQUery ajax call return an html error

Tags: ajax, jquery

Hi I am just learning to work with jquery and ajax.And an tryin gto berform a basic jquery call and retrieve an ok.But it seems I get back nothing.

This is my html:

```
<a href="#" class="addToCart" id="'.$idProduct.'" name="cart">Add to Cart</a>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
$('.addToCart').on('click', function(){
        var itemId = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'cart.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: itemId,
            dataType:'html',
            success: function(result){
                alert(result + " ceva ");
            },
            error : function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

And this is my php code:

```
echo $_POST['cart'];
```

When I try to run this in the success alert I get back this:

[image]

How can make this ajax call to work properly?

Comment: The error message in the popup is just html code returned from the server saying that you have a PHP error in line 8 of cart.php

Answer (score 1):

You have to send your post data in key/value pairs, try

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cart.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {cart:itemId},//key -> cart, value -> itemId
        dataType:'html',
        success: function(result){
            alert(result + " ceva ");
        },
        error : function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have an error in your PHP code. The returned HTML has some text that says "Notice: Undefined index" etc.

The AJAX Call succeeds - so you're seeing the alert message.